# NSString to C string

Tags: objective-c

I'm new with Objective C.

I would like to know why this code does not work fine. The idea is to make a function that copies the content of a NSString into a Cstring.

I send a message to setAttr, i.e: [ self setAttr:@"something"]

```
- (BOOL) setAttr:(NSString *) src{
 const char *dst;

 [ self NSString2CString: src  dst: dst ];

 printf("%s",dst); // <-- gives me junk
 return YES;
}


- (BOOL) NSString2CString: (NSString *) src dst: (const char *) dst {
 const char * __src= [src UTF8String];
 if ( (dst=(const char *) malloc( strlen(__src)+ 1) ) == NULL) return NO;
 strcpy(dst, __src);
 return YES;
}
```

thanks

Comment: I'm not using the NSString methods, like getCString, because, afaik:
the C string I receive is owned by a temporary object, and will become invalid when automatic deallocation takes place.
That is why I'm copying it.

Comment: "Converts the receiver’s content to a given encoding and stores them in a buffer." *You* provide the buffer, so how long it lives is up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method `-NSString2CString:dst:`, `dst` is a local variable. Your `malloc` to `dst` won't be reflected back to the caller.

To allow the caller to receive the new `malloc`ed pointer, you need to pass by reference:

```
-(BOOL)NSString2CString:(NSString*)src dst:(char**)p_dst {
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ...
   if ( (*p_dst = malloc( ... )) == NULL ) return NO;
   strcpy(*p_dst, __src);
}
...
char* dst;
[self NSString2CString:src dst:&dst];
```

---

BTW,

1. If you have got an NSString, don't use `strlen`, use `[src length]` instead.
2. You know there's already [a method called `-getCString:maxLength:encoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/getCString:maxLength:encoding:)?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation
1. great advice
2. yes, I think the returned block of memory will be freed when performing a release operation on the src, so, that is why I'm copying the c string.

Comment: @jhon: But at least you could remove the `strcpy` call with this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in the **address of the `cstring`** (using the [address-of operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators) `&`) not the pointer:

`[ self NSString2CString: src  dst: &dst ];`

Your method prototype should now look like this:

`- (BOOL) NSString2CString: (NSString *) src dst: (const char **) dst`

**But why do this when `NSString` already has a method called [`-getCString:maxLength:encoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJGIEIE)?**

Comment: This also means that the method has to be modified to take a `const char**` instead.